SharePoint 2013 extremely slow
I've been utilizing SharePoint 2013 on-premise, and it had been functioning smoothly until recently when its performance significantly declined. Within the setup, I've configured workflows for task generation and forwarding. Incremental crawling is scheduled daily at 7 PM and typically completes within 5-10 minutes, while full crawling occurs every 4 months. Whenever a task is created or forwarded to a user, an email alert is triggered. Additionally, when an announcement is uploaded to SharePoint, email alerts are dispatched to approximately 70 recipients. The server hosts four sites, equipped with 32 GB of RAM and 2 TB of storage. Currently, the accumulated data consists of around 800 GB of documents/files, totaling approximately 80,000 documents. However, in the past couple of days, the performance has drastically deteriorated. Upon analyzing the log files, I've observed recurring warnings.
sometimes when clicked on new task creation or forward button it says 'something went wrong while displaying this page. error code out of memory'
05/20/2024 15:28:08.99 w3wp.exe (0x10B4) 0x1D44 SharePoint Foundation Configuration 8059 Warning Alternate access mappings have not been configured. Users or services are accessing the site http://myprod with the URL http://'192.168.0.205'. This may cause incorrect links to be stored or returned to users. If this is expected, add the URL http://192.168.0.205 as an AAM response URL. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=114854"/>
05/20/2024 14:58:08.57 w3wp.exe (0x10B4) 0x1CF4 SharePoint Foundation Monitoring b4ly Medium Leaving Monitored Scope (Render Ribbon.). Execution Time=10.34904 cb792aa1-7d7e-009f-404f-4ff82defd1f7
05/20/2024 14:58:08.60 w3wp.exe (0x10B4) 0x1CA4 SharePoint Foundation Request Management advu2 High [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 05/20/2024 14:58:08.10, Original Level: Verbose] Size of data: '{0}' bytes cb792aa1-7d7e-009f-404f-4ff82defd1f7
I have done following  ......

continuous crawling is set to once per day.
distributed cache is stopped


There are many reasons for this. Based on the information you provided, one possible cause could be the size of your accumulated data, another possible cause could be the recurring warnings you observed in the log files.
Please check as follow steps:
1, Check the server's available memory and storage to ensure that it meets the minimum hardware requirements for your SharePoint deployment.
References：
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/web-content-management-capacity-and-performance
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/redesign-topology-for-more-content-and-users
2, Check the SharePoint Central Administration website for any crawl health reports related to crawl freshness.
Reference：
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/redesign-for-specific-performance-requirements
3, Check the log files for any recurring warnings or errors. such as the warning related to alternate access mappings not being configured. Follow the instructions in the warning message to add the URL as an AAM response URL.
4, Consider increasing the available memory for the Distributed Cache servers.
Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/social-performance-and-capacity
